# ISC DHCP Server - A Client's Uplink Is Not Working

Tags: debian, iptables, routing, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

Running a DHCP server, client(s) does not have up-link (0Mbps) and has a downlink (50Mbps.)

I am setting up a gateway/router on a PC running Debian Wheezy with ISC-DHCP. I have 1 WAN (eth0) and 2 LAN (eth1, eth2) interfaces connected.

Do I need an IP table rule to allow upload packets on eth1/eth2 to go out of eth0 to the Internet? The problem is that users cannot submit web forms or uploading data to websites.

Below is interfaces and iptables outut:

```
cat /etc/network/interfaces

# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet6 auto
iface eth0 inet static
        address 173.xxx.xxx.145
        netmask 255.255.255.252
        gateway 173.xxx.xxx.146

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 192.168.2.10
        network 192.168.2.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
        address 192.168.22.10
        network 192.168.22.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

```
iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Jul 15 08:33:07 2014
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [5430:3921752]
:INPUT ACCEPT [362:33625]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [5047:3846737]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [187:27214]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [5234:3873951]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jul 15 08:33:07 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Jul 15 08:33:07 2014
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [285:25527]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [123:23976]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [165:24524]
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth2 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i eth2 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jul 15 08:33:07 2014
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Tue Jul 15 08:33:07 2014
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [227:16114]
:INPUT ACCEPT [68:5796]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2:668]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:668]
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 ! -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.22.0/24 ! -d 192.168.22.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.50.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Jul 15 08:33:07 2014
```

Comment: Update: some clients get full upload speed while others receive 0 upload speed (using speedtest.net). These clients are on windows and linux.

One person answered "How can you establish incoming traffic when ACKs are not able to be sent because of missing upstream?" but I am unsure what he means. This was said on http://serverfault.com